# Returning sample json in Response using swagger

Tags: jersey, swagger, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I am using swagger with my dropwizard application for API documentation and for non dependant UI development.

I have to return mock responses which can contain sample serialized response objects which I created.

For example :-

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get User")
@PermitAll
@Path("/users/{userId}")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.OK_200, message = "User", response = User.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN_403, message = "You are not authorised"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND_404, message = "User Not Found!"),
})
public User getUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
}
```

I want to return a sample(mock) User object created by me. I can always add that code in my actual controller function till the time i write actual implementation, but that wont be a clean solution and also i want to have my mock responses working parallely with actual response.

I went through the swagger-core documentation and found that there's way to have mock requests(through @Example annotation) but not mock responses.

Is there a way to do it.?